# Transitions effect between pages with svg image, css, html, js

Tags: javascript, html, animation, svg, css-transitions

Ok, maybe stackoverflow can help? :)

I'm trying, without any luck, to create a page transition effect with an svg image.
When the user clicks on a link in Page 1, a diamond shaped svg fades in like a portal into Page 2.

The basic idea is to recreate the space travel in the intro of the Alphaville - Forever Young video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t1TcDHrkQYg
:)

Maybe the diamond also fades in from blue to transparent (but that is the next step).

Diamond svg: https://www.onlinewebfonts.com/icon/413

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) instead of a svg since animating an svg that big will be really slow and really laggy. You can change the clip path to show what you want. [Bennet Feely](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) created a nice generator that helps with this.

For the animation itself you can increase the width and height to fit your screen. Then fill the remainder by animating the Z axes.

Animation looks better in fullscreen then in the smaller preview

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".page-transition");
const overlay = document.querySelector(".overlay__diamond");

for(const link of links) {
  link.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    overlay.classList.add("overlay__diamond--animate");
    
    setTimeout(() => window.location.reload(), 1000);
    
    // This one is correct, one above is for the demo
    // setTimeout(() => (window.location.href = link.href), 1000); // Same time as animation duration
  });
}
```

```css
.page {
  background: green;
  
  /* For demontrational purposes only, just to increase page size */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  perspective: 500px; /* Needed for translateZ to work */
}

.overlay__diamond {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  animation: fadeout 1s linear forwards;
}

.overlay__diamond--animate {
  animation: zoom 1s linear forwards;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 75% 50%, 50% 100%, 25% 50%);
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    transform: translateZ(0);
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: translateZ(400px); /* Can't go higher then the perspective */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <!-- Replace #link with your actual urls -->
  <a class="page-transition" href="#link">Link</a>
  <a class="page-transition" href="#link">Link</a>
  <a class="page-transition" href="#link">Link</a>
  
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="overlay__diamond"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Reyno for quick answer and the clever solution! It works like a charm! I'm very happy for now, :D The next step is to see the next page through the diamond, but thats require an another technology I guess. I am testing som stuffs.

Comment: @hardin81, that's actually pretty easy, just let the `div` fadeout on pageload. Then when you navigate it looks like its smooth. Of course the page will always flicker form loading unless you use something like react or vue. See snippet for example

Comment: Thanks agin for helping me with this! It works and it's looks cool. I changed the background of the diamond to a space image background thats fading to tranparent. Just as I wanted! Thank you!